# Portforwarding on android with a static ip on mobile data

Tags: linux, port-forwarding, android, iptables

I recently called my cell carrier and bought a static ip, I don't have wifi so I use my phone's hotspot as my main source of internet. I have a laptop with an ubuntu vm and I've realized how limited it is without proper port forwarding. I can open a port on my phones localhost and it opens that port on my public ip and my hotspot ip too, what I want to know is how I could open a port on my ubuntu vm or windows itself and then port forward that to my public ip.

Answer (score 1):

You need reverse port forwarding. It's probably called "reverse" because it's
actually setting up a "reverse proxy" in which a HTTP server running on your phone
accepts connections on a port and wires them to your computer.

This is accomplished using
[adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)
with the following command:

```
adb reverse tcp:<phone-port> tcp:<local-port>
```

References:

- [How to Install ADB on Windows, macOS, and Linux](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/)
- [Port forwarding during usb tethering](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66564/port-forwarding-during-usb-tethering)

Comment: I don't think this will work. `adb reverse` opens on my Android 9 system only a port on localhost on the device: e.g. using port 8000 for adb reverse netstat on Android shows `tcp        0      0 localhost:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Comment: I tried doing "adb reverse tcp:8080 tcp:4545" and it keeps saying more than one device/emulator

Comment: Okay I fixed that, now it just opens on my localhost and not my public ip

Comment: @jaker As I wrote in my comment this happens on my device, too. Therefore I would assume that this answer does not or no longer work. May be it was limited up to a certain Android version. As workaround you can use `adb reverse` for opening a port (on a different port) on localhost and then use Termux + socat to open the real public port that forwards everything to the adb reverse port on localhost.

Comment: @Robert Okay so I got the reverse adb working and my localhost on my phone redirects me to the port on my pc, now how to I get the port on my public IP open aswell. Also i'm using kali nethunter because Termux doesn't work with the root on my phone, it's some weird permission denied error.

Comment: @jaker As I wrote use `socat` to open a public port and forward it to the adb forwarded port on localhost.